# iOS: Put checkmark on preselected row on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using Xcode 5.1 with iOS7.  In my app I have a static uitableview made up of several sections, each has 2-3 rows.  I used a static table because this my settings view controller and the contents will not change.

In one such section I have 2 rows.  Each row has a label on the right side, similar to the iPhone's General --> Auto-Lock rows.

Like the auto-lock row, when the user selects the row it segues to another tableview controller made up of several rows.  Whenever a user selects a row here, I show a checkmark.  When the user backs out of this vc I show the name of their selection in the label on the right-side of the row, again just like the auto-lock example.

I use an unwind segue to pass the selected value back (from detail to master, you could say) so I know what the user selected and that's how I set the value in the label that's sitting on the row.

What I'd like to do is be able to already have the detail tableview row checked with the last value the user selected (again, like the auto-lock example).  I know the name of what they selected because I send it over in the `prepareForSegue`.  I don't know how to tell the tableview which row to put the checkmark because the detail table doesn't have any connection to the master table, sending 'indexPath.row' wouldn't work.  Because I have a small amount of rows, I could just check each row and see if its text is equal to the text that I sent over.  I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it, though, because I'd like to allow the user to enter their own text in these labels in a future release.  I'd appreciate any ideas.  Thanks!

EDIT: I should better clarify my issue and what help I'm looking for.  I have 2 rows in a Settings table that both segue to a detail table.  This detail table contains several rows of static data.  At the time the user selects a row from this detail table, I don't know which row from the Settings table is making the request; I just hand back the label on the row thru an unwind segue.  Because of this, I need to be able to look up the value of the data (sent from the Settings table) on the 'viewDidLoad' of the detail table. I'm sorry for not making this clearer from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply record the row (or also section, if you want) under a `NSUserDefaults` key. In `viewDidAppear` you can set the checkmark.

This would work in any event. If you allow editing and, say, deletion of a row, you can adjust this setting on the fly. Equally, changing the text of the label would be irrelevant.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  ...
  if (indexPath.section == kTrackedSection) {
      NSInteger selectedRow = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:kSetting];
      if (selectedRow == indexPath.row) { return; }
      UITableViewCell *otherCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      otherCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:indexPath.row ForKey:kSetting];
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mundi.  I think your first sentence is the problem I'm having.  I only have 2 rows on the master table but 6 on the detail.  There isn't a direct correlation between the rows on the master and the rows on the detail, so I can't say "row 4 on the master is the same as row 4 on the detail".  I know the value of the row because I send it to the detail in a segue.  I just don't know how to identify the correct row on the detail table in order to put a checkmark on the detail row.

Comment: If it is a static table you should know the where everything is. Just make sure you rely on your data model (such as the user defaults) to find out and persist.

Comment: It's true, I do know where everything is but because I want to give the user the ability to add/edit/move the rows in the detail tableview I was looking for help in interrogating that tableview by content.  I don't know how Apple does it, they do the same pattern in a dozen different places.

Comment: You asked how to store the selected row and I told you. That is independent from how many rows there are, or what the strings are. If you want, you can also store an array of strings in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Since I already know how to add a checkmark to a row, because I already do this now as I indicated in my question, I don't think your suggestion will work for me.  I appreciate you taking the time to respond, though.

Comment: It is not about putting the checkmark on the cell, it is about persisting this information. Anyway, if the answer helped you, which it should, you should accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you but that answer did not help me because your answer did not address my question.  I have clarified my question.

Comment: Looks like a royal waste of time. Thank you.